# Checkers 1V1 , can't move

Tags: python

I'm writing a project about checkers (1V1). When I'm trying to move the soldier, it's print the same board, what I'm doing wrong? thanks

Example : I'm trying to move from 2X3 to 3X4

```
rows = 8
cols = 8
board = [['B', '-', 'B', '-', 'B', '-', 'B', '-'], ['-', 'B', '-', 'B', '-', 'B', '-', 'B'],
             ['B', '-', 'B', '-', 'B', '-', 'B', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
             ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', 'w', '-', 'w', '-', 'w', '-', 'w'],
             ['w', '-', 'w', '-', 'w', '-', 'w', '-'], ['-', 'w', '-', 'w', '-', 'w', '-', 'w']]
def create_game_board():  ##### this function create the game board#####
    for i in range(rows):
        list = []
        for j in range(cols):
            list.append(" ")
        board.append(list)
    return board

validTurn = True

def valid_Move_position(board):
    currentRowCube = input("what is the row of the player that you want to move? ")
    currentColCube = input("what is the col of the player that you want to move? ")
    targetRowCube = input("which cube do you want to move to? ")
    targetColCube = input("which cube do you want to move to? ")

#def move(,targetColCube, targetRowCube ):
    #if (targetRowCube, targetColCube =="-"):
        #currentRowCube = "B"
        #currentColCube = "B"

def print_board(board):  #####This function is drawing the board#####
    print("    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ")
    print("    A B C D E F G H ")
    for i in range(cols):
        print(i, " |", end="")
        for j in range(rows):
            current_cell = board[i][j]
            print(current_cell + "|", end="")
        print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `create_game_board` is malfunctioning. If your aim is to create a copy of the default board, then you can use one-liners for that. Your function instead appends a list of 8x8 spaces to the default board, therefore modifying it.

I suggest you try this:

```py
def create_game_board():
    return [[v for v in line] for line in board]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your move function doesn't work, you never move the pieces, when you set `currentRowCube = "B"`, in the function move, that only assigns it locally, and you can't expect that to change it in the list.